# Как закрыть консоль после выполнения приложения?

Tags: c#, консоль, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Приложение Selenium, после выполнения консоль остается на экране. Выкинул все из кода, оставил только инициализацию и закрытие драйвера - все по-прежнему. Что делать?

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System;

namespace Myspace
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

            driver.Close();

        }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
  public class Program
  {
    private static void Main()
    {
      IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

      driver.Quit();
    }
  }
}
```

Похоже что это баг, на их баг-трекере баг заведен.

[WebDriver.close() does not close browser window](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/654)

**UPD**: Кстати если использовать оператор `using` то всё закрывается корректно:

```
private static void Main()
{
  using (IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver())
  {

  }
  //driver.Quit();
}
```

Потому что метод `Dispose` как раз использует операцию `Quit`:

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
  try
  {
    this.Execute(DriverCommand.Quit, null);
  }
  /*...*/
}
```

Comment: Ссылку бы хотя бы привели на баг.